# Lie group - exponential Diffeomorphism

Tags: lie-groups, exponential-function

Let $G$ be a nilpotent, connected simply connected Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. It is known that the exponential map $\exp$ is a diffeomorphism.

Now let $\mathfrak{g}_0$ be a Lie subalgebra and a Lie ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$, and $G_0$ its Lie group.

Is the exponential map $\exp\colon\mathfrak{g}_0 \rightarrow G_0$ still a diffeomorphism ?

Comment: The exponential map is not a global diffeomorphism in general.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $G$ is nilpotent...

Comment: The restriction of a diffeomorphism to an embedded submanifold (in this case a linear subspace) is always a diffeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: You can hind a complete answer and discussion here:
https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~sgc/teaching/exp.pdf